Order by on joined table is really slow
I have a jobs table that is left joined with job_events table. The job_events table has an index on type and jobId.
When I order the query by jobs.id the results show up in under 200ms. When I order by job_events.created_at it takes 1.74s.
How can I improve this query so that it runs in under a 1s.
Here is the SQL query
SELECT *
FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN job_events ON job_events.jobId = jobs.id
    AND job_events.id = (
        SELECT MAX(id) FROM job_events 
        WHERE jobId = jobs.id
    )
LEFT JOIN job_events created_by_events ON created_by_events.jobId = jobs.id
    AND created_by_events.type = 'Created By'
    AND created_by_events.id = (
        SELECT MAX(id) FROM job_events 
        WHERE jobId = jobs.id AND type = created_by_events.type
    )
LEFT JOIN job_events completed_job_events ON completed_job_events.jobId = jobs.id
    AND completed_job_events.type IN ('Job Completed', 'Job Complete')
    AND completed_job_events.id = (
        SELECT MAX(id) FROM job_events 
        WHERE jobId = jobs.id AND type = completed_job_events.type
    )
WHERE status IN (5, 6)
ORDER BY job_events.created_at
LIMIT 101;


Mysql explain details:


You not only join tables, you also have sub-queries. You could make a temporary table in which you store the result of SELECT MAX(id) FROM job_events GROUP BY jobId, TYPE, which you then use in the sub-queries. Don't forget to index jobId and TYPE. Remember you can make one index on multiple columns. I have no real idea whether this will speed up your query significantly, but a bit of experimenting can't hurt. Often people try to push everything into one query, thinking that must be the fastest solution, but many times it isn't. Your question is missing the table definitions.

@KIKOSoftware I have already attempted that and it hardly speeds up things.

You join three times the same table and use select *. You should only select the columns of job_events you need. If it's only a few columns, you could make an combined index on all of them.
Then the database has no need to read the whole record...

I'd use temporary tables for job_events filtered by different type values that you have in each subquery.

@Turo While good advice, I don't think what you select will have a significant impact on join and sort performance.

When ordering by jobs.id the server only needs to evaluate the joins until it has enough rows to satisfy the limit clause. When ordering by job_events.created_at it has to evaluate the joins for every jobs row.
You have not included the DDL or any information about the distribution of the data, so this is a bit of a stab in the dark.
You could move the calculation of the three separate aggregates to a subquery and use conditional aggregation:
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT j.*,
        MAX(je.id) AS max_id,
        MAX(IF(je.type = 'Created By', je.id, NULL)) AS max_created_by_id,
        MAX(IF(je.type IN ('Job Completed', 'Job Complete'), je.id, NULL)) AS max_completed_id
    FROM jobs j
    LEFT JOIN job_events je ON j.id = je.jobId
    WHERE j.status IN (5, 6)
    GROUP BY j.id
) AS temp
LEFT JOIN job_events je1 ON je1.id = temp.max_id
LEFT JOIN job_events je2 ON je2.id = temp.max_created_by_id
LEFT JOIN job_events je3 ON je3.id = temp.max_completed_id
ORDER BY je1.created_at ASC
LIMIT 101;

